# how does the preload functionality been implemented by webpack?

Tags: html, webpack

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "EmojiPicker" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
    /* webpackPreload: true */
    "./EmojiPicker"
).then(module=>console.log(module))
```

I wrote an async import in my code, and then use dev-severer to launch the app.

I found that there was no `<link rel="preload">` added into `head` during loading time.

So I am wondering how does webpack implement this functionality?

Comment: Does it appear at all in the page? Does anything in your page actually use your module? (Tree-shaking may cause WebPack to elide it).

Comment: there's network request which showed in dev-tools, so it does be loaded into the page.

Comment: Devtools will show you what triggered the request (be it XHR, `<script async>`, `<script defer>`, `<link rel="preload">`, `<link rel="prefetch">`, etc)  in the Initiator column in the Network tab - what does it say?

Comment: requireEnsure @ bootstrap:128
./src/component/Chat.js @ Chat.js:24